# Solc: Source file requires different compiler version

Tags: solc, compiler, import, version-pragma

in my brownie project i have imported [LinkTokenReceiver.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/LinkTokenReceiver.sol) contract which its pragma solidity is `pragma solidity ^0.7.0;`, which means that it requires compiler version equal or greater than 0.7.0, and when i compile with compiler version `0.8.7` **(which is greater than 0.7.0)**  it throws this error

> Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.Windows.msvc) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
> --> C:/Users/Dell/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink@1.10.0/contracts/src/v0.7/LinkTokenReceiver.sol:2:1:

> 2 |    pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

can someone explain why and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways

- Update the source file to be compatible with a newer solidity versions,
  this is a manual process of updating the program, reading through the source code and understanding that nothing breaks when you bump up the compiler version
- Use an older version compiler for your project as a general